# Use my computer as a controller/keyboard for the PS3

Tags: playstation3, controllers

I imagine that I should be able to pair my computer to my PS3 via bluetooth and use my computer as a controller for the menus and for typing. Are there any open source projects that have done this? If not, where should I start to write my own? Maybe just look at the drivers people have written to pair their computer to the PS3 controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [HIDClient](http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en) on Linux for this. It makes your computer emulate a Bluetooth keyboard, and you can customise it at will (add scripting or triggers) since the source code is available.

I will let someone else research the equivalent software for Windows, because I could not find anything satisfying.

Answer (score 2):

Um...you can just plug a regular USB keyboard directly into the PS3, and I'd imagine you can also pair any Bluetooth keyboard with it as well.  What's the computer needed for?

Comment: I guess his project will lead to letting people play ps3 games on computer! although via an actual ps3 console in the corner!

Comment: What I'm doing certainly could lead to that! My intentions right now are to be able to use Siri to open Netflix on my PS3 or other similar tasks. I've already got the part with Siri working.